# Boolean comparison of a MultiIndex to one of its values

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I'd like to compare a value of a `MultiIndex` to the whole index, to get a boolean array for other processing. This works fine for a regular integer index, but for some reason it doesn't compare equal for `MultiIndex`.

For example:

```
>>> i = pd.Index([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
>>> i == i[0]
array([ True, False, False, False, False])

>>> i = pd.Index([(1, 2), (3, 2), (3, 3), (4, 1), (5, 2)])
>>> i == i[0]
array([False, False, False, False, False])
```

How can I achieve this comparison? I'm sure it is doable with looping through the index, but *there's got to be a better way*.

Comment: Just curious as what *other processing* you need here. IMHO, usually index is for indexing/slicing.

Comment: @QuangHoang True and applicable. It is for indexing a corresponding Numpy array that doesn't have the tuple index. I know one option would be to convert the array to a data frame, but honestly this piqued my interest to the point I want to know how to do it simply because.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This *really* piqued my interest, and I think I might have come up with a satisfying solution. It involves the use of [pandas.MultiIndex.difference](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22.0/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.difference.html)

```
non_matching_tuples = i.difference(pd.Index([i[0]])) # this gets all non-matching indices
desired_output = ~i.isin(non_matching_tuples) # this should give your desired output
```

Let me know if this satisfies your curiosity, I think it's pretty much what you were looking for.

Comment: Not as clean as I'd like, but thanks for the solution!

Comment: Fair enough, I'm also looking forward to other solutions

Comment: Me too, this really seems like it should be a oneliner in Pandas or just work for out of the box with the way I tried. But I'll for sure accept this if no better ways are found!